# Update Apache 2.2.22 to 2.2.25

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates, apache2

I need to update Apache to version 2.2.25 on ubuntu 13.04
I have tried installing the update from apt-get but the package is showing as 2.2.22

Can anyone help?

Comment: also important to read http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install *yet* Apache 2.2.25 using apt-get because Apache 2.2.25 is not yet included in Ubuntu repositories. To see what versions are available in repositories, you can use the following command:

```
apt-cache showpkg apache2
```

But you can install by downloading it from here:

- http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22

It's a `.tar.gz` file ([httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz](http://apache.cs.utah.edu//httpd/httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz)), so you can be interested also by:

- [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Thank you Radu, yes I checked and that is the only way but this brings me to another question. Can I upgrade directly or do I need to uninstall the previous installation? Also, will I get updates if apt repository gets update later?

Comment: @deadmantfa If you install httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz  you will have two apache servers, so if you want, you can remove the previous installation. And no, you will not get updates until the new version is not included in Ubuntu repositories.